# Why thread is required

Tags: vb.net

I am new to a desktop application and seeing that there are threads used everywhere.

I don't understand why we are using it here and not in webapplications.

We can directly call the method instead of threads.

Comment: Do you have any examples of "everywhere?"

Comment: Have you looked at the code to see where and why it is creating threads?

Comment: I use them plenty in web applications, when they are needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Threads used everywhere' is probably an ominous sign of problems to come and possibly past incompetence, but the main reason people use multiple threads in desktop applications is to allow long-running things to happen without freezing the user-interface of the application.

A conventional Windows GUI app has a 'main thread' which is responsible for processing messages received from the OS.  These messages are used for all mouse/keyboard interaction, so the moment you stop processing them, the application stops responding (after a few seconds of this, Windows itself will grey-out the app and put 'stopped responding' in the title bar.)

To avoid this ugliness, people move activities which take a long time (either because they need a lot of CPU, or because the may be waiting for I/O (disk, network, etc)) onto other threads.  This means that the main thread is free to keep pumping messages.

You do not start the main thread explicitly - Windows gives it to you when the app starts.

You need to be very careful about interaction between background threads and the main thread - there are a bunch of rules and restrictions, and failing to follow them will give you the kind of problems which may not show up immediately, consistently or on your machine at all.  That doesn't mean they're not there...

Comment: Great answer, I think it is worth mentioning (or elaborating) the issues multithreading could bring if your not careful. That is, when multiple threads share a common resource, deadlocks and race conditions can occur. If you have threads waiting on each other to finish their work on a common resource, you defeat the purpose of threading to begin with! :)